# how can I attach and detach usb-device(webcam) programmatically in un-rooted android device?

Tags: java, android, usb

[image]

as title, How can I detach and then re-attach USB-device programmatically in android java?

because of approach permission does not persist and maintained
after the device(unrooted power-plugged device) reboot,

I am finding a way to create unplug and re-plug specific usb-device(which I know about its PID and VID of this device)

Is there any ways to create detach and re-attach event programmatically
in an un-rooted android device?

or any other way to maintain already granted USB-device approach permission
after the device reboot?